# How to capture photo programmatically without user interaction

Tags: iphone, ios, security, camera

I want to capture a photo programmatically and without using **camera app**, without even notifying to the user. Actually this is for security app. Please let me know if its possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

taking a picture without being the foreground app is not possible

Comment: using local notifications or push notifications when we are in application recieve notification method can we start camera and capture image?